# unable to use return in a try-block inside a class

Tags: php, class, return, try-catch

I have problems implementing the following method:

```
private function query($statement, $params = array(), $name = ""){

    try{
        $this->prepare($statement, $name);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }   
    try{
        return $this->execute($name, $params);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

the second try-block should return the value from another method called. I call it this way:

```
$resultset = $db->select('SELECT * FROM tabelle WHERE "ID" > $1', array(1));
var_dump($resultset);
```

and get a NULL.
If i var_dump the value inside the try-block, I get a result:

```
private function query($statement, $params = array(), $name = ""){

    try{
        $this->prepare($statement, $name);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }   
    try{
        var_dump($this->execute($name, $params));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
}
```

> array(3) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(13) "name1"
>   ["time"]=> string(26) "2012-09-11 20:23:38.854918" } NULL

What I am doing wrong?

**edit** the part between $db->select and the posted method:

```
public function select($statement, $params = array(), $name){
  $this->setQueryType("select"); // just a setter
  return $this->query($statement, $params, $name);
}
```

Comment: And no exception is thrown while getting this null?

Comment: Is that all the code? You said you are calling using $db->select correct?

Comment: yes there is no exception thrown. @LloydMoore sorry I forgot one part, i'll edit my question.

Comment: Does not make sense to me why it will dump the output, as if `$this->execute` does return something, but the `try` block will not return that specific value

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the return value from execute and return it at the end of the method and see if it works?

```
private function query($statement, $params = array(), $name = ""){
  $return = false;
  try{
    $this->prepare($statement, $name);
    $return = $this->execute($name, $params);
  }
  catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also doesn't work. Could you please explain what you meant with you last sentence? Possible exceptions are thrown inside the other methods, e.g. execute().

Comment: Yea sry, never mind my last sentence. It would only make sense to me that an execption is being thrown somewhere without noticing.